# ng-model not binding two way in a modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this `html`

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-positive">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
        </ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleLeft()">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>

      <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right" name="main-view">
      </ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
      <div class="list">
        <a menu-close href="#" class="item item-icon-left">
          <i class="icon ion-home">
          </i>
          Home
        </a>
        <a menu-close href="#/product" class="item item-icon-left">
          <i class="icon ion-home">
          </i>
          products
        </a>
        <a menu-close href="#/category" class="item item-icon-left">
          <i class="icon ion-home">
          </i>
          Category
        </a>

      </div>

    </ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>
  <script id="product.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="products">
      <ion-content>
      <div class="list">
        <a class="item" href="#/product-form?id={{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{nome: searchText}">
          {
            {item.nome}
    }
      <span class="item-note">
        {
          {item.quantidade}
    }
  </span>
  </a>
  </div>    
  </ion-content>
    <div class="tabs tabs-icon-top">
      <a class="tab-item" href="#/product-form">
        <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
          Adicionar
  </a>
            <a class="tab-item" ng-click="openModal()">
              <i class="icon ion-search"></i>
                Filtrar
  </a>
  </div>     
  </ion-view>
  </div>
  </script>

  <script id="search.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios7-search placeholder-icon"></i>
          <input type="search" placeholder="busca" ng-model="searchText">
  </label>
            <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeModal()">
              cancelar
  </button>
  </div>
  </script>
</body>
```

And with this `controller`

```
angular.module('ionicApp.controllers', ['ionicApp.config', 'xc.indexedDB'])
    .controller('ProductController',
        function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout,
            $ionicModal, $indexedDB, $window, $ionicModal) {
            $scope.safeApply = function (fn) {
                var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
                if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
                    if (fn && (typeof (fn) === 'function')) {
                        fn();
                    }
                } else {
                    this.$apply(fn);
                }
            };

            var OBJECT_STORE_NAME = constants.productStore;
            $scope.items = [];
            $scope.searchText = "";

            $scope.getAll = function () {

                var myObjectStore = $indexedDB.objectStore(OBJECT_STORE_NAME);

                myObjectStore.getAll().then(function (results) {
                    // Update scope
                    $scope.safeApply(function () {
                        $scope.items = results;
                    });
                });
            };

            $scope.getAll();

            $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('search.html', {
                scope: $scope,
                animation: 'slide-left-right'
            }).then(function (modal) {
                $scope.modal = modal;
            });

            $scope.closeModal = function () {
                alert($scope.searchText);
                $scope.modal.hide();
            };

            $scope.openModal = function () {
                //$scope.searchText = "a";
                $scope.getAll();
                $scope.modal.show();
            };

            $scope.closeModal = function () {
                alert($scope.searchText);
                $scope.modal.hide();
            };
            //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
            $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                $scope.modal.remove();
            });
            // Execute action on hide modal
            $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function () {
                // Execute action
            });
            // Execute action on remove modal
            $scope.$on('modal.removed', function () {
                // Execute action
            });

        })
```

**Edit**

Here is where i define the `ProductController`

```
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionicApp.controllers']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: "/",
            views: {
                'main-view': {
                    templateUrl: "home.html",
                    controller: "AppCtrl"
                }
            }
        })
        .state('product', {
            url: "/product",
            views: {
                'main-view': {
                    templateUrl: "product.html",
                    controller: 'ProductController'
                }
            }
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});
```

My problem is the `searchText` model isn't updating when the value changes. I tried `$watch`, `ng-options`.

I can put a initial value to the `$scope.searchText` on `openModal` method, but after inputed values don't update the model value, because of this my list isn't filtered.

Anyone could help me?

Thanks.

**Edit 2**

I solved the problem adding the search text into the modal.

```
    $scope.modal = modal;
    $scope.modal.searchText = "";
```

And i changed the attribute to the new variable.

```
<input type="search" placeholder="busca" ng-model="modal.searchText">
```

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Have you tried to look in $scope.modal.searchText?

Comment: The  $scope.modal.searchText is undefined

Comment: As it should be – I don't see that specified anywhere. Where is `ProductController` implemented?

Comment: .controller('ProductController'(...) I think here is where the ProductController is implemented.

Comment: That's where you define it, but where in markup are you attaching it to the page and utilizing it? Also, where is your `ng-app` defined?

Comment: @CharlieS i edited the question, the ng-app is defined on html tag

Comment: can you give me a jsfiddle

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two-way binding works best with a nested object. Change your bindings to use something like this

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.items = [];
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm newbie in angularjs and i dont understand the answer

Answer (score 0):

The template for the modal is still being requested before the modal is in scope.  That's probably the reason